# Check constraint before insert a value into the database

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique-constraint, check-constraints

I'm trying to create a table to store **order_details**. The table has a column **status** that should only be allowed to contain the value *true* once per each `order_id`, but may contain the value *false* multiple times per `order_id`.

```
create table order_details (
    id serial, 
    order_id integer not null, 
    status boolean not null
);
```

I want to do this within the table structure itself. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a filtered unique index:

```
create unique index on order_details(order_id)
where status;
```